# can't GETjson data in <option> box as a drop dow list

Tags: php, html, json, getjson

I'm having a problem with my website i need to make for Uni, i'm supposed to create a site that only uses one HTML page to show tables in a database, allow the user to search through the data and delete the data.

What i'm trying to do is show all the tables as options in a dropdown box and then showing each individual table in it's entirely but can't get it to work. 
I managed to get it to work before but now it doesn't work anymore. 
I'm using the getJSON method to get the information from a PHP page.

I have written the code below i am having trouble with

```html
<script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
function setupTableNamesList() {
     $.getJSON ("getTableName.php", function jsondata() {
             if ( jsondata.names.length > 0 ) {
                var html1 = '<select id="tablename" name="tablename">';
                html1 + = '<option value="none">Please select a table</option>';
                for ( i = 0; i < jsondata.names.length; i++ )
                    html1 + = '<option value="' + jsondata.names[i] +'">' + jsondata.names[i] + '</option>';
                html1 + = "</select>";
                $("#reports").html(html);
                $("#tablename").change( changeHandler );
             }
    }//function
);
```

Comment: Typo `$("#reports").html(html);` should be `$("#reports").html(html1);`

Comment: You need to fix your script tag at the top, the syntax is `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Also, you should enclose all of your javascript function in a `<script>` tag too.

Answer (score 0):

Typo `$("#reports").html(html);` should be `$("#reports").html(html1);`.

**Update**

You forgot `}` for the `if`:

```
if ($("#tablename").prop("selectedIndex") > 0) {
  $.getJSON("getTableData.php?tablename=" + $("#tablename").val(),
    function(jsondata) {
      if (jsondata.rows > 0) {
        var html = '<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"><thead><tr><th>Row</th>';
        for (i = 0; i < jsondata.columns; i++)
          html += "<th>" + jsondata.headings[i] + "</th>";
        html += "</tr></thead><tbody>";

        for (row = 0; row < jsondata.rows; row++) {
          html += "<tr><td>" + (row + 1) + "</td>";
          for (column = 0; column < jsondata.columns; column++)
            html += "<td>" + jsondata.data[row][column] + "</td>";
          html += "</tr>";
        }
        html += "</tbody></table>";
        $("#tablearea").html(html);
      } // <----------------------------------- You forgot this here.
    });
}
```

Comment: I changed that and it still doesn't work. no idea why i doesnt work http://at-web2.comp.glam.ac.uk/students/13025902/PDO/index222.html

Comment: @Jordan'clem'Thomas `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: that's strange it seems to load with chrome but it's just a blank page

Comment: @Jordan'clem'Thomas I am using Chrome too. Check console by pressing `F12` button.